# On Premise Doodle for SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am looking for a solution to have the functionality of 'Doodle' on a on-premise SharePoint 2013 farm.

Up until now what I could find online was either more than outdated or the company went bankrupt already.

Anyone here who knows a good 'offline' Doodle?

TIA

Comment: What's the **Doodle**?

Comment: Doodle helps you to schedule meetings and other things....https://doodle.com/en_GB/.  @AM2FTW, As far as I am aware it is not possible without any custom development

Comment: I guess so too. I think it could be done rather simple with a list and a workflow but a 'fancy / sexy' solution or App would be nice.

Comment: I have developed "Doodle for SharePoint" solution for on-premise SharePoint 2013 / 2016. If you are interested I could also provide you more information on this or a demo version.

Comment: Yes please.....how can I contact you? Do you have a site..?

Comment: the website is currently in development, please send me an email to maxim@tarassenko.de and I will response you with the details!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's alright according to the rules to just link to ready-made solutions...

The only Doodle-like Add-On I know is MeetSweet: https://www.meetsweet.com/ - the O365 Add-In is free, the OnPrem variant you have to request a quote.